# How can I get intent confidence in the IBM Watson Assistance user interface?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I can get intents confidence via the JSON response object by back-end languages like Node or Python, but I can't get that in the browser-based IBM Watson Assistant user interface. Is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<? intents ?>` to get the information on the intents.

The object is read/writable in dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Assistant online tool to edit workspaces and the dialog elements has the "Try it out". However, it does not have the capabilities yet to explore the JSON structure returned by the message API.

What I use is this [tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) which allows to test a conversation, see and edit the context and inspect the confidence levels. There is also another, browser-based, [tool](https://conversation-inspector-for-ibm-watson.mybluemix.net/home) you could use. None of them are official.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use network tools on your browser to see the Json of the whole message being passed around.

Typically you right click anywhere and click “inspect element” and then go to the network tab.